# What is wrong with my 8tb WD HDD? superblock unreadable until unmount,unplug,replug,remount

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dmesg

Sorry for my lack of a good name for the question but I am having a really hard time with my WD 8tb hdd that I am using for snapshots in opensuse leap 15.4.  It is practically brand new.  It is plugged into a sata port on a pcie expansion card.  I have a few drives plugged into it and all the others seem alright.

It has a gpt partition table and one big 8tb partition.  It is formatted in ext4.
I run Back In Time on it to do snapshots.
Unfortunately I keep having to unmount,unplug,replug,remount it to get it to work. I would have to do this about once every 3 or 4 days, but I believe it is happening daily now.
I run a simple `fsck /dev/sdf1` on it and it says it is ok.

Here are parts of my dmesg log:

```
[257941.032543] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 7365202232 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[257941.032567] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 920650023, lost async page write
[257941.032610] ata40: EH complete
[257941.060192] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.060227] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.060247] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.060264] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 30 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.060304] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.060320] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.162206] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.170315] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.170339] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.170408] ata40: EH complete
[257941.210153] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.210185] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.210206] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.210225] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 5 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.210277] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.210298] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.310965] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.314594] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.314637] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.314734] ata40: EH complete
[257941.336881] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.336918] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.336936] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.336951] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 12 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.336990] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.337006] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.349168] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.352980] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.353024] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.353099] ata40: EH complete
[257941.376880] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.376917] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.376941] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.376960] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 16 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.376998] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.377014] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.379918] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.383722] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.383766] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.383841] ata40: EH complete
[257941.420168] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.420211] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.420235] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.420258] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 20 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.420327] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.420354] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.513441] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.521676] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.521721] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.521806] ata40: EH complete
[257941.556811] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.556842] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.556863] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.556882] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 9 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.556933] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.556954] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.662266] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.665933] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.665970] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.666049] ata40: EH complete
[257941.683512] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.683552] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.683570] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.683589] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 13 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.683643] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.683665] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.700010] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.703807] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.703850] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.703921] ata40: EH complete
[257941.730175] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.730213] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.730232] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.730247] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 23 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.730287] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.730302] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.832511] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.840868] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.840913] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.840988] ata40: EH complete
[257941.863478] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.863517] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.863539] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.863560] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 2 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.863612] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.863628] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257941.870338] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.874003] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257941.874047] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257941.874118] ata40: EH complete
[257941.913485] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257941.913518] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257941.913536] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257941.913551] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 6 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257941.913589] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257941.913605] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257942.002648] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257942.014769] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257942.014812] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257942.014893] ata40: EH complete
[257942.030149] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257942.030188] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257942.030208] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257942.030223] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 10 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:00:30:08/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257942.030262] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257942.030279] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257942.040479] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257942.044097] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257942.044141] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257942.044215] sd 39:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=1s
[257942.044223] sd 39:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#10 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[257942.044227] sd 39:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#10 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[257942.044232] sd 39:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#10 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 b7 08 30 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[257942.044235] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 7365734400 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[257942.044260] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 920716544, lost async page write
[257942.044305] ata40: EH complete
[257942.063422] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257942.063454] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257942.063473] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257942.063488] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 13 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:10:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257942.063527] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257942.063543] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
[257942.071330] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257942.074838] ata40.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[257942.074845] ata40.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[257942.074901] sd 39:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#13 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=1s
[257942.074902] sd 39:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#13 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[257942.074903] sd 39:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#13 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[257942.074904] sd 39:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#13 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 b7 40 08 10 00 00 00 08 00 00
[257942.074905] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 7369394192 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[257942.074910] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 921174018, lost async page write
[257942.074918] ata40: EH complete
[257942.123363] ata40.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[257942.123376] ata40.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[257942.123380] ata40.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[257942.123382] ata40.00: cmd 35/00:08:88:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 tag 16 dma 4096 out
                        res 61/04:08:88:08:40/00:00:b7:01:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[257942.123389] ata40.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[257942.123391] ata40.00: error: { ABRT }
```

smartctl

```
root: ~> smartctl -a /dev/sdf
smartctl 7.2 2021-09-14 r5237 [x86_64-linux-5.16.2-lp154.9-default] (SUSE RPM)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD80EAZZ-00BKLB0
Serial Number:    WD-CA2GNBBK
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2c03b03cc
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    8,001,563,222,016 bytes [8.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5640 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Apr  2 23:22:09 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (24764) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 952) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   252   242   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6366
4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       13
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       348
10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       13
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       440
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   118   107   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 43020 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 43020 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 347 hours (14 days + 11 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
-- -- -- -- -- -- --
04 61 02 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.992  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.990  IDENTIFY DEVICE
ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.990  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.989  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.893  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 43019 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 347 hours (14 days + 11 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
-- -- -- -- -- -- --
04 61 46 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.990  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.989  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.893  IDENTIFY DEVICE
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.860  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 43018 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 347 hours (14 days + 11 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
-- -- -- -- -- -- --
04 61 02 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.989  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.893  IDENTIFY DEVICE
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.860  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.857  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 43017 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 347 hours (14 days + 11 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
-- -- -- -- -- -- --
04 61 02 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.860  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.857  IDENTIFY DEVICE
ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.857  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.856  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.843  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 43016 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 347 hours (14 days + 11 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
-- -- -- -- -- -- --
04 61 46 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.857  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.856  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.843  IDENTIFY DEVICE
ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      22:14:50.822  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       346         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       323         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       218         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       182         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       141         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       117         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        93         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        69         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        45         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

let me know if you need any more info.
Thanks, really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the card I bought for pcie to sata is no good. It is this card on amazon: [10 port x4 pcie to sata  using asm1166+jmb575](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09F2KB143).
For one, I had to flash the firmware on it using an old mobo that had windows and had to hunt down the image to flash.  This was just for my drives to be seen on my Asus Prime Z690-A.

From my reading anything above 2 ports on an x2 and maybe 4 ports on an x4 is going to be problematic on these pcie to sata cards.  But I will be staying away from them altogether.

What I did was buy a [m.2 5 port sata expansion on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B8TV1QRG).  This seems to be working well.  We will just have to see.

However I also bought a [4 port LSI SAS hba x4 card and breakout cables, not included](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005UO2I4M).  Most are x8 because most are 8 port. I don't have a spare x8. Anyway, I hear good things about these types of cards so I will be excited to try it out once I get it.